# Issues with adding Prometheus as a datasource to Grafana

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana

I have a single, locally run, docker instance with containers for Grafana(**v8.4.0-43439pre**) and Prometheus(**2.32.1**), when I try to add Prometheus as a datasource to Grafana the WebUI gives me the following error: **Error reading Prometheus: Metric request error**
and the Grafana logs gives me the following error: **first path segment in URL cannot contain colon**

When adding the datasource I use *serverip*:3200 as the URL.

Both are clean containers, no other configurations made.

**Grafana**:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name grafana grafana/grafana:main
```

**Prometheus**:

```
docker run -d -p 3200:3200 --name prometheus prom/prometheus:latest
```

I've searched for this issue, but couldn't find an issue or solutions that's quite the same as mine.

*This is my first time working with any of these applications, hope someone can help me out.*

Comment: Have you tried `http://serverip:3200`?

Comment: @PaulBurrows When I change it to http:// I get the following error: _lvl=eror msg="Instant query failed" logger=tsdb.prometheus query=1+1 err="Post \"http://serverip:3200/api/v1/query\": read tcp 172.17.0.2:36312->serverip:3200: read: connection reset by peer"_

Comment: By default Prometheus will be listening on port 9090, so you'd need to run it with `-p 9090:9090` or if you really want to access it on port 3200 then `-p 3200:9090`

Comment: @PaulBurrows this did the trick, shows that I need to learn more about assigning ports to a container thank you very much and have a pleasant new years eve.

Comment: Good to hear it. I've added it as an answer if you could kindly mark it as an accepted answer. Thank you and happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

Had to run the container with `-p 3200:9090` instead of `-p 3200:3200` to assign the port 3200 to 9090 which is the right port.

Answer (score 1):

The following error can be fixed by including `http://` in the URL for the datasource:

```
error: first path segment in URL cannot contain colon
```

Prometheus listens on port 9090 by default, so you can either run the container using that port:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --name prometheus prom/prometheus:latest
```

Or if you want to use another port you should map that to 9090:

```
docker run -d -p 3200:9090 --name prometheus prom/prometheus:latest
```